# How does Ajax prioritise the data field with multiple forms?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a page with multiple Bootstrap modal forms which submit and edit data.

These are done by including the forms which are on other PHP pages and this works fine when there's only one form on the site.

If I remove the Edit Form, the Add form works fine. I'm positive this is due to the Javascript elements, however, I can't understand how it specifies any other form other than the one it is nested under.

**Index.php:**

```
<!-- Add Modal-->
          <div class="modal fade" id="addModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add Offence</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                    <?php include_once('addRecordForm.php'); ?>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

<!-- Edit Modal-->
  <div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="editModalLabel">Edit Records</h5>
          <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <?php include_once('editRecordForm.php'); ?>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**custom.js**

```
// Delete Records
$(function() {
    $( ".delbtn" ).click(function(){
        var itemID = $(this).attr("id");
        console.log(itemID);
        $.ajax({
            url:"delete.php", //the page containing php script
            data: { id: itemID}, // itemID passed as id
            type: "POST", //request type
            success:function(result){
                //alert(result);
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Error occured');
            }
        });
    });
});

$(function() {
    //#add-record-form grabs the form id
    $('#edit-record-form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'editRecord.php',
            method:'post',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(msg) {
                //alert('Records Edited!');
                location.reload();
            }               
        });
    });
});


//Add Records 
$(function() {
    //#add-record-form grabs the form id
    $('#add-record-form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'addRecord.php',
            method:'post',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(msg) {
                //alert('Records Added!');
                location.reload();
            }               
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$('form')` selector returns a collection of all `form` elements on the page, and `serialize` doesn't work on collections, so it's operating in the *first* element it encounters: `#add-record-form`.

Comment: Hi @msg, thanks for the reply. This is something I had tried and had no luck, I have updated OP to reflect the changes

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. that makes much more sense :)

Comment: @BradlySpicer Just tested and that's not the case, is only inside `success` and `error` callbacks where the context changes, I'm getting expected values on post even using `$(this).serialize()`